# working sample needed with new OAuth2 dialog with a popup window

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-timeline

I am looking for a working code which displays a popup window for authorization just like washington post reader. The example shown on fb developers site is just a button (add to facebook) on html. I am looking for a full working sample with popup window and add-to-timeline functionality using PHP SDK preferrably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these Sample Apps by Facebook 
Run with Friends at http://github.com/facebook/runwithfriends/zipball/master

Or a few sample Apps at here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/samples/

Comment: Your Welcome can you please approve my answer !